# How to add HTML5 in netbeans 6.9.1

Tags: html, netbeans

Just now I have started using netbeans 6.9.1.
    I want to create a HTML5 file which will give me drag and drop event.
    Can anyone tell me how to do this.
    Does netbeans6.9.1 support HTML5 and css3.if not How to add html5 to netbeans..

```
Thanks
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no HTML5 support in Netbeans 6.9.1, it was I think introduced in version 7.  You can easily upgrade an existing Netbeans installation to the latest version (7.2 was just released), all your settings will be saved - and the old version remains entirely functional, should you need features that are abandoned in later versions.

Comment: thanks now i am using netbeans7.but can you please tell me how i can create a html5 file in this netbeans...